# instanceof behavior while doing incomplete inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

In this example:

```
/**
 * Transform base class
 */
function Transform() {
    this.type = "2d";
}

Transform.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "Transform";
}

/**
 * Translation class.
 */
function Translation(x, y) {
    // Parent constructor
    Transform.call(this);

    // Public properties
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Inheritance
Translation.prototype = Object.create(Transform.prototype);
// Here I purposely omit Translation.prototype.constructor = Translation;

translation = new Translation(10, 15);

console.log(Translation.prototype.constructor); // Transform
console.log(translation.__proto__); // Transform
console.log(translation.constructor); // Transform

// Yet this is true!
console.log(translation instanceof Translation);
```

Can someone explain why `translation instanceof Translation` is `true` if neither `__proto__` nor `constructor` contain `Translation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true because `translation` is an instance of `Translation`. In general `new X instanceof X` is true.

Algorithmically it's true because `Translation.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf( translation )`, and that's what the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator tests for.

It starts there and continues down the prototype chain, so `translation instanceof Transform` is also true, because:

```
Transform.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.getPrototypeOf( translation ) )
```

and `translation instanceof Object` is also true, because:

```
Object.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.getPrototypeOf( translation ) ) )
```